# Analyzing impact of a training program when performance increases have diminishing returns

Tags: hypothesis-testing, paired-data

I am testing a hypothesis that a training program impacts employee performance.
My dataset consists of employee performance as measured by a unit output (e.g. 150 units, 201 units, etc.) in two consecutive periods (before (p0) and after (p1) training), as well as a binary flag of whether the employee received the training. The improvement in performance from p0 to p1 based on training v. no training is what I'm interested in.

My issue with the data stems from two facts:
1) Whether the employee received the training is at the manager's discretion and therefore partially influenced by the employee performance in p0, ie lower performing employees tended to receive the training to correct performance.
2) Performance in output of units can only rise so high, and someone with a lower performance in p0 (say, 100 units) has much more room for potential improvement than someone already crushing it with 300 units (in fact it's likely that their performance will decrease in p1 because it would be difficult to repeat a 300unit period.
Together, these two facts mean that on average, employees who receive training have more potential for gain than employees who don't.

How can I account for the non-randomness of the "treatment" application and the phenomenon of (p1-p0) being dependent on starting position p0?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reformulate you question(s) a little which also help clarify your thinking.

If I understood correctly, I believe that you ultimately want to understand if training employees is boosting performance.  You do have some concerns namely (a) there may have been some bias in selecting who got training and who did not and (b) there also may be affect related to prior performance.

So, first off, I am *assuming* that you have several measurements of employee performance pre-training and then several measurements post-training. In that case I am pretty sure you have described a longitudinal study that is also called [repeated measures design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeated_measures_design).  Subjects were monitored for some time and then an intervention (`training`) and you are interested in its effect on the subjects.

The simplest method for investigating this is repeated measures ANOVA which is just a generalization of the two-sample test you may be familiar with but repeated measurements are made on the same individuals. There are lots of more sophisticated analyses you can look at but here is a nice start:  [Repeated Measures Analysis of Variance Using R](https://www.uvm.edu/~dhowell/StatPages/R/RepeatedMeasuresAnovaR.html).

With respect to you second comment, it is pretty easy for you to code the employees in to categories (e.g. High Performers vs Low, or High, Medium, Low). Then you simply re-run your repeated measures ANOVA with factors.  That way you can see if the training helps everyone, or just some particular groups.  It is not about the "ceiling" but instead how you characterize the groups.  As an aside, by putting your employees into these buckets you'll also be able to help with your first concern (bias in who got training and who did not).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response; you have correctly interpreted my question/intentions.
I do not actually have several measurements, I only have two per employee, 1 for p0 and one for p1.
I have actually tried bucketing employees based on performance, but even within a bucket (using 3 buckets), there is a bias in training selection (trained employees have a statistically significant difference in performance from untrained employees in p0). Is there a rigorous method for choosing my bucket ranges / number of buckets?